# Ngx-editor not showing in any browser

Tags: angular, font-awesome, ngx-bootstrap

I just added `ngx-editor` version 3.3.0 in my angular application. However, when I add the line below in my `app.module.html`

```
<app-ngx-editor [placeholder]="'Enter text here...'" [spellcheck]="true" [(ngModel)]="htmlContent"></app-ngx-editor>
```

nothing displays on my browser.
I have also added `formsModule`, `font-awesome module` and `ngx-bootstrap` module to my project in app.module.ts. Below is my `app.module.ts`:

```
...
import { FormsModule} from '@angular/forms'
import { NgxEditorModule } from 'ngx-editor';
import { AngularFontAwesomeModule } from 'angular-font-awesome';
import { TooltipModule } from 'ngx-bootstrap/tooltip';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    UserListComponent,
    SendMenuComponent,
    UsersRecordComponent,
    AdminAddComponent,


  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AngularFireModule.initializeApp(environment.firebase),
    AngularFireDatabaseModule,
    FormsModule,
    ToastrModule.forRoot(),
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    NgxEditorModule,
    AngularFontAwesomeModule,
    TooltipModule.forRoot(),

  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Answer (score 0):

I finally solved this problem by adding the line:

```
htmlContent = '<p>Hi</p>';
```

to my `app.component.ts` file. This was used to set the value of your `[(ngMode)]` attribute in `app-ngx-editor` tag i.e  `[(ngModel)]="htmlContent"`.

Also by default, the height of the editor is kinda compressed. We can set the properties of the editor by adding an `[config] = "editorConfig"` property directive to the `app-ngx-editor` tag and assigning the value in the `app.component.ts` file i.e

> app.component.html

```
<app-ngx-editor [config]="editorConfig" [placeholder]="'Enter text here...'" [(ngModel)]="htmlContent"></app-ngx-editor>
```

> app.component.ts

```
editorConfig = {
    editable: true,
    spellcheck: false,
    height: '70em',
    minHeight: '5rem',
    width: '100%',
    translate: 'no'
  };

  htmlContent = '<p>Hi</p>';
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by changing the html tag from `app-ngx-editor` to `ngx-editor`.
Also, I did this after following [this](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-editor) documentation.